# Is there way to skip empty value ticks?

Tags: highcharts

I've got a chart with data represented by timestamp/value combination, so I use 'datetime' for xAxis. On line chart it looks all great, but on column it shows empty space for days with no values.
Is there a way to use last value as filler or skip this empty space (e.g. after June 1s show tick for June 3rd)?

[image: Bar chart]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use breaks:

```
    xAxis: {
        breaks: [{
            from: 3,
            to: 9,
            breakSize: 1
        }]
    }
```

**Live example:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/xr9j7ybc/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.breaks

---

Or `oridinal` property from Highstock:

```
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        ordinal: true
    }
```

**Live example:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/x0Ljh19v/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/xAxis.ordinal